# Equalizing the audio of another app - how to?

Tags: java, android

i need to make a Equalizer for Android. 
El audio session ID 0 is deprecated.
Is there a way to get the current audio session ID?
I want to equalize from my app the sound of other apps.
In Google play there are other apps that use the "compatibility mode". but i do not know how they do it. For example, the app detects that spotify is playing, the session is selected and it can equalized.
Does anyone know how do this? 
Thanks.

Example applications:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devdnua.equalizer.free

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=devdnua.equalizerp.free

[image: Example][image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION), you can use ACTION_OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION to receive the id of a playing audio session:

> Intent to signal to the effect control application or service that a new audio session is opened and requires audio effects to be applied.

I tried adding the constant (and many others) in the manifest, but it only worked for music apps such as Spotify and Youtube Music:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.AudioSessionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.OPEN_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_SESSION"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then, you can use the id to create an equalizer attached to the session id.

```
public class AudioSessionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(Equalizer.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, -1);
        String packageName = intent.getStringExtra(Equalizer.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME);
    }
}
```

When I play my own media file (with my own test app), there are equalizer apps that still work on it even though I didn't broadcast the session id of my media player. So there must be a solution involving a Service that doesn't rely on Broadcast Receivers.

Comment: unable to detect when song play  in Jio saavn music player

Comment: Developers have to explicitly fire the OPEN action, it isn't done by default. Initially I was confused by why this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jazibkhan.equalizer&hl=en_CA&gl=US) works despite global mix being deprecated, then I realized that global mix was simply still working on my OnePlus phone by making a test app. 

I tried [decompiling](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) some apks but didn't find anything. There was some code I didn't understand the purpose of, maybe there is a workaround to be found there.

Comment: so what did u find so far?

Comment: Nothing, just that global mix still works on some devices. I vaguely remember there was some kind of service that did something with MediaPlayer or something in the decompiled code, but I couldn't understand how it works; I think it created a media sesssion on top of others somehow and then they used that session to an id to pass to the [equalizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer). You can try using the global mix method to see if it works on your device, if it doesn't but an equalizer app still works, then a workaround might exist.

Comment: Oh right, I also found a way to get all session ids using  [MediaSessionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions(android.content.ComponentName)), but this is only for apps with "settings" level permissions